# How to Add custom text before product's price in product details page in Magento 2?

Tags: product, price, magento-2.1.3

I am working with ***Magento 2.1.3*** and i want to add some ***custom text*** before ***product's price*** in product details page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make changes in `price-box.js` which is placed at

> /vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/js/price-box.js

Make sure you take this js in your custom theme folder and make changes on line number 22 near 
`priceTemplate: '<span class="price"><%- data.formatted %></span>'`

Add your custom text after `<span class="price">`

Some thing like this,

```
priceTemplate: '<span class="price">Price - <%- data.formatted %></span>'
```

Done.

Comment: i have made changes but i confuse where i place this file in my custom theme folder ?

Comment: Copy price-box.js from this path /vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/js/price-box.js

And paste it at below path,
/app/design/frontend/Custom/Theme/Magento_Catalog/web/js/price-box.js

Create this path if not exists.

And make changes at line number 22, like 
priceTemplate: '<span class="price">Price - <%- data.formatted %></span>'

Run below commands at terminal,

>php bin/magento s:up
>php bin/magento setup:di:compile
>php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
>php bin/magento c:c

Comment: i paste price-box.js in to above mention folder and i clean cache but nothing change.

Comment: Run below commands at terminal, >php bin/magento s:up >php bin/magento setup:di:compile >php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f >php bin/magento c:c @MohdHasan

Comment: Done ? @MohdHasan

Comment: php bin/magento setup:di:compile returning allowed memory size exhausted error

Comment: it is solved. Your answer is correct. Thanks